# How to push values to array in one function and read it in another function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Here is my code:

```
var myObject = [];
function something() {
    myObject.push("thing");
}

function other() {
    console.log(myObject);
}
```

How can I let `other` see the items pushed into `myObject` by `something`?

Comment: `console.log(myObject[0])`?

Comment: I do have the feeling that you execute `other` *before* `something` ...

Answer (score 1):

It's declared globally - so just calling `something()` then `other()` will ensure that there are elements in the array. If you were calling them in the wrong order, then the function was displaying the empty array first, then adding an element to it.

```js
var myObject = [];

function something() {
  myObject.push("thing");
}

function other() {
  console.log(myObject);
}

something();
other();
```

If you want to log each item on a separate line:

```js
var myObject = [];

function something() {
  myObject.push("thing");
}

function other() {
  myObject.forEach(e => console.log(e));
}

something();
something();
something();
other();
```

Also, you're dealing with an *array*, not an object. An object looks like this:

```js
var anObject = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: true,
  key3: 42.01
};

console.log(anObject);
```

Comment: and when i have declared globally but i have function in function and want to call it in other function?

Comment: "this happens by default" what happens by default? Also are you sure that the question in its current state can be answered already?

Comment: i have this but ready function cant read that from message function. https://pastebin.com/EAqpQtzf - either is array declared, i missed that

Comment: Sorry @JonasWilms - I meant to add the function order. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Edited @JonasWilms